# Reading from Firebase Database without crashing

Tags: android, firebase

I'm creating an app that requires me to read from a fire base database and this value to alter layouts. I've tried using the 'help' from android studio but when I run the program it crashes. The photo I've attached is the 'help' not as code because it crashed the program and I wanted it work basically. So can anyone advise an easier method of reading from the database?

Thanks

```
12-04 11:38:44.004 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11020
12-04 11:38:44.004 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
12-04 11:38:44.034 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Collection enabled
12-04 11:38:44.034 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: App package, google app id: com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending, 1:723788589244:android:e3ad2acca46870b3
12-04 11:38:44.034 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                                             adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending
12-04 11:38:44.034 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
12-04 11:38:44.104 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
12-04 11:38:44.114 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Using measurement service
12-04 11:38:44.114 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Connecting to remote service
12-04 11:38:44.114 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-04 11:38:44.264 3524-3524/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: onActivityCreated
12-04 11:38:44.514 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Using measurement service
12-04 11:38:44.514 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-04 11:38:44.514 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 60750091
12-04 11:38:44.514 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
12-04 11:38:44.514 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignUpActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=531904640859358265}]
12-04 11:38:44.544 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Using measurement service
12-04 11:38:44.544 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
12-04 11:38:44.744 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending D/FA: Connected to remote service
12-04 11:38:44.744 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
12-04 11:38:44.794 3422-2815/? V/FA-SVC: Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignUpActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=531904640859358265}]
12-04 11:38:44.804 3422-2815/? V/FA-SVC: Saving event, name, data size: screen_view(_vs), 59
12-04 11:38:44.804 3422-2815/? V/FA-SVC: Event recorded: Event{appId='com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending', name='screen_view(_vs)', params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=SignUpActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=531904640859358265}]}
12-04 11:38:44.814 3422-2815/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3418911
12-04 11:38:44.814 3422-2815/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
12-04 11:38:44.814 3422-2815/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling task with Gcm. Time3418911
12-04 11:38:44.824 3422-2815/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 28
12-04 11:38:49.854 3524-3630/com.example.jopayne1968.points4spending V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but can you be a little more clear? And also can you share what code did you use that crashes the app?

Comment: sorry if im not be clear, i used android studio's help code for firebase but this caused my app to crash so im looking for someone to provide maybe an alternative code that doesnt make it crash? the code i used is the image attached in my post

Comment: In that case, can you share your logcat so that we can see where exactly is the app crashing?

Comment: i was unable to add it as a comment but i editted it inot my question

Comment: This is not it. When your app crashes, you must be getting multiple red lines in the verbose, those are the errors. Share those.